# jQuery add remove class on list with a delay in between

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add a class to a div, then remove the class and move on to the next div and do the same. The following works almost perfectly:

```
var f = jQuery('.ls-slide').find('div.main-img-label');

function recursive(i) {
    f.removeClass('blue-flash').eq(i).addClass('blue-flash');
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % f.length)
    }, 3000);
}
recursive(0);
```

Only difference is that I would like a delay in time between the removal of the class and the addition of the class on the next item.

For example the div.main-img-label is a red circle, the class blue-flash changes the circle to blue. But it looks like the blue moves from one to another and I would like one to turn blue, then them all be red again before another circle turns blue.

Comment: Move the `addClass` statement inside the timeout. `var f = jQuery('.ls-slide').find('div.main-img-label');

function recursive(i) {
    f.removeClass('blue-flash')
    setTimeout(function () {
        f.eq(i).addClass('blue-flash');
        recursive(++i % f.length)
    }, 3000);
}
recursive(0);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that change made nothing turn blue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function recursive(i) {
    f.removeClass('blue-flash');
    setTimeout(function () {
        f.eq(i).addClass('blue-flash');
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % f.length)
    }, 3000);
}
```

or

```
function recursive(i) {
    f.removeClass('blue-flash');
    setTimeout(function () {
        f.eq(i).addClass('blue-flash');
        setTimeout(function () {
            recursive(++i % f.length)
        }, 2000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

UPDATE: fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/9ya46tj4/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both of these options dont work, the circle never changes color.

Comment: Yes you are correct, very sorry. Thank you for your help! I have used the jfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add some extra delay in each iteration...
[Updated code]

```
function flashLoop(){
var timeout = (1000 * $('.main-img-label').length);
  setInterval(function(){
  $.each($('.main-img-label'), function(i, el){
      setTimeout(function(){
         $(el).addClass('blue-flash');
          setTimeout(function(){
              $(el).removeClass('blue-flash');
          },500);
      },1000 + ( i * 1000 ));
  });
  }, timeout);
}
    flashLoop();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this made no change, the change is still instant without a delay

Comment: Can you maybe add a fiddle so i can see what you are doing?

Comment: ok so here is the jfiddle result:
https://jsfiddle.net/adeblath/3n6ot1qk/1/embedded/result/

how do i share the whole thing?

Comment: The link to 'the whole thing' is this : https://jsfiddle.net/adeblath/3n6ot1qk/1/light/ But what are you excatly trying to do?

Comment: I would just like there to be a delay in between the change in colors, so all the circles are red before the next one turns blue. Currently it moves straight onto the next one, i would like a half second pause before the next one changes to blue

Comment: Brilliant, how can i make it repeat again? only runs once through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98231/discussion-between-keyboard-ninja-and-adrian).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the jQuery's delay() method?
https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Something like:

```
var f = jQuery('.ls-slide').find('div.main-img-label');

function recursive(i) {
    f.removeClass('blue-flash').delay(800)
     .eq(i).addClass('blue-flash');
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(++i % f.length)
    }, 3000);
}
recursive(0);
```